# Calculating logarithms in vb.net - conflicting results

Tags: vb.net, excel, math

I am doing some calculations in vb.net, this is my equation:

```
rms = (20 * (Math.Log(rms / 0.7746))) 'also tried (Math.Log10(rms / 0.7746))
```

I have tried various different methods of writing this, including separating out the calculations into various steps. However the final result is quite far out.

I have tried declaring my variable 'rms' as a decimal and a double. It does contain decimal places.

In Excel, I have tried the same calculation using this formula:

```
=20*(LOG(C2/0.7746)) ' where C2 is the RMS value
```

And the results are consistent with a website I used to check, as well as my pocket calculator.

I have also tried rounding the number to 3 decimal places:

```
rms = Math.Round(rms, 3)
```

This too has a minimal effect on the final result.

I can only assume it's the 'operator precedence' in VB but I'm struggling to work this one out.

Any help greatly appreciated as always, thanks.

Comment: just check - 20 * (Math.Log10(100.0)) should result 40

Comment: In your Excel formula, the LOG function defaults to base 10. If that gives you the result you want, you need to use `Math.Log10` in your VB.Net statement. You said you tried that, but when I use `Math.Log10`, I get the same result as the Excel formula.

Comment: Yes, I get 40 as expected with both of the following: In Excel: =20*(LOG(L6)) - in VB: MsgBox(20 * (Math.Log10(100.0)))

Comment: In  VB: Dim myresult = (20 * (Math.Log10(0.779 / 0.7746)))
        myresult = Math.Round(myresult, 3)
        MsgBox(myresult) = 0.049 - in Excel = 0.054 !!

Comment: True result is 0.0491993. Both hand calculation and Excel

Comment: When asking a question about why different approaches give differing results, it helps to include in your question *exactly* what you tried in each case (including the values of any variable you used), and exactly what results you obtained.  Testing here https://dotnetfiddle.net/ I get the "correct" result 0.049199

Comment: Is it possible you formatted C2 to use 3 decimal places.  If the actual value is something like 0.7794 and is formatted to display 0,779, you would get 0.53658

Comment: I think I have been a bit *thick* (maths / programming is not my forte - this is just a 'hobby horse') - after setting the decimal places to 16 across all programs I seem to be getting (fairly!) consistent results, at least to the first 9 decimal places. My apologies for wasting people's time - I honestly thought I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After a marathon debugging session I found an error in my code.

I have a routine that uses the voltage at a given frequency to "normalise" all the plots I do to 0dBu.

My normalisation routine was broken. Badly.

And finally - to get the correct output from the log maths, I had to change the order in which the calculation was performed.

It was originally `rms = (Math.Log10(rms / 0.7746) * 20)`

In trying to find the issue, I changed it to `rms = (20 * (Math.Log(rms / 0.7746)))`

Which yields a different (and incorrect) result.

In any case - it's fixed now.

Thanks to all who responded.